# can we use echo with >> logfile ; in the end semicolon in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sh

(e.g)
code in unix shell script

echo "Hello world " >> $LOG_FILE;

is the syntax correct . can we use semicolon at the end or not ?

Comment: By the way, in general, you should enclose any variables you access in double quotes, e.g. `echo "Hello" >> "$LOGFILE"`

Answer (score 0):

Semi-colon `;` is bash command separator. If you only have one command in a line it is unnecessary, but harmless.